How can i find my public ip ? for configuring bindings on my local server and publish it to the web
I have a Node.js app that I'm trying to deploy on IIS and publish using Windows Server. However, I’m stuck on assigning IP addresses to my bindings.
I also have a domain with A records pointing to the same IP address as my IIS server, so the DNS records are set up correctly. Despite this, my website is only visible from my local device and not accessible externally.
I initially tried using IP addresses in the ranges 192.168.x.x and 172.30.x.x, but I realized these are private and local. As a result, my site with the configured domain is not accessible from my phone or other devices; it only opens on the desktop hosting my IIS server.
In summary, is there a public IP address on my device that can be used to make my IIS website accessible? How can I obtain one?
I'm glad for any help.
Thanks in advance...

Server administration and networking are off topic on this programming-centric site, and you should consult your server/network administrators for proper guidance. In short, IIS Manager's binding dialogs give you all the IP addresses (or all unassigned) options to you, and you cannot go beyond that due to TCP/IP basic rules. I left some more hints in https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/self-hosting-series-why-cannot-my-web-server-iis-be-reached-from-anywhere-else-8da0e0b252ef

I resolved the issue by configuring my router settings. I needed to route the public IP (provided by the router) to my local IP, mapping the appropriate ports for proper redirection is key factor, Thanks tho.

@ExpoMan I'm glad you got it to work.  And you can turn this comment into an answer and accept it, which will help more people who are facing the same problem.

I resolved the issue by configuring my router settings. Which provided by my ISP...
All we need setting our router what engages external requests by port forwarding to our static local ip from public ip. here is detailed explanation:
https://medium.com/@afikrim/setting-up-port-forwarding-and-dns-825897bf2459
Good Luck With It...
